# jQuery resize function doesn't work on page load

Tags: jquery, onload-event

How do I get this function to not only run on window resize but also on initial page load?

```
$(window).resize(function() {
...  
});
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This solution is now deprecated since jQuery 3.0: https://api.jquery.com/bind/#bind-eventType-eventData-handler

You'll want to use:

```
$(document).ready(function() { /* your code */ });
```

To make something happen onload. If you want something to work onload and onresize, you should do:

```
onResize = function() { /* your code */ }

$(document).ready(onResize);

$(window).bind('resize', onResize);
```

Answer (score 8):

I think the best solution is just to bind it to the load and resize event:

```
$(window).on('load resize', function () {
    // your code
});
```

Comment: This is the most straightforward answer of all

Comment: This makes it simple and clean.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is by design.

You should put your code into a named function, then call the function.

For example:

```
function onResize() { ... }

$(onResize);
$(window).resize(onresize);
```

---

Alternatively, you can make a plugin to automatically bind and execute a handler:

```
$.fn.bindAndExec = function(eventNames, handler) {
    this.bind(eventNames, handler).each(handler);
};

$(window).bindAndExec('resize', function() { ... });
```

Note that it won't work correctly if the handler uses the `event` object, and that it doesn't cover every overload of the `bind` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(onResize);
$(window).bind('resize', onResize);
```

didn't work with me.

Try

```
$(window).load('resize', onResize);
$(window).bind('resize', onResize);
```

instead.

(I know this question is old, but google sent me here, so...)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, you can simply setup a handler, and spoof a resize event yourself:

```
// Bind resize event handler through some form or fashion
$(window).resize(function(){
  alert('Resized!');
});

// Trigger/spoof a 'resize' event manually
$(window).trigger('resize');
```