# how to reuse a jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JQuery: $(window).resize() doesn't work on Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597152/jquery-window-resize-doesnt-work-on-load)

I have the below jQuery function. I  want to use it twice. Once on window resize and again on page load without having to repeat myself. I have tried the below which works on resizing the browser window but the function is not working when I try to run again it on page load.

```
 window.onresize = function resize(event) {
    if(window.innerWidth < 620 ){
        $('#secondaryNav').hide();
        $('#search form').prependTo('div.content');
    } else{
        $('#secondaryNav').show();
        $('.content form').appendTo('#search');
    }

}

window.onload =  resize(event);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should have searched before posting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597152/jquery-window-resize-doesnt-work-on-load

Comment: @Sudhir. I don't think it is a great post but it doesn't deserve so much downvotes. There're a lot worse question that even have positive votes.

Comment: Note that older IE versions create two functions for named function expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function resize(event) {
    if(window.innerWidth < 620 ){
        $('#secondaryNav').hide();
        $('#search form').prependTo('div.content');
    } else{
        $('#secondaryNav').show();
        $('.content form').appendTo('#search');
    }

}

window.onresize = resize:

window.onload = resize;
```