# jQuery Window Resize while having a .bind click function

Tags: jquery, syntax, if-statement, window-resize

I'm repurposing a smooth scrolling to anchor script, and my site is attempting to practice responsive web design. I find myself needing to have the click event only function while the browser width is greater than 900px.

```
$(function() {
    if($(window).width() > 900){
        $('article').bind('click',function(event){
            stuffHappens;
        });
    }
});
```

I've also tried using the window .resize function but the results are quite buggy. The final result needs to work on load, and check on browser resize *(in case it needs to enable or disable)*. Suggestions?

```
$(window).resize(function() {
});
```

Comment: Duplicate of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597152/jquery-window-resize-doesnt-work-on-load

Comment: So you want the click event to work only if the window size > 900?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="clickme">Click Me</div>
    </body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var handler = function(){
                console.log("clicked");
            };
            var $window = $(window);

            var setClickHandler = function(){
                if($window.width() > 900){
                    var registered = false;
                    var events = $(".clickme").data("events");
                    if(events){
                        var handlers = $(".clickme").data("events").click;
                        if(handlers){
                            $.each(handlers, function(index, e){
                                if(e.handler == handler){
                                    registered = true;
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    if(!registered){
                        $(".clickme").on("click", handler );
                    }
                } else {
                    $(".clickme").off("click", handler );
                }
            };

            setClickHandler();
            $window.on("resize", setClickHandler);
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

It looks little complicated but this is the best I could come up with.
Here we registers and unregister the handler based on the window width.

Another simple solution is to check the condition within the handler

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
            var handler = function(){
                if($window.width() > 900){
                    console.log("clicked");
                }
            };
            var $window = $(window);

            $(".clickme").on("click", handler );
        });
```

Comment: Sorry Arun I couldn't get that script to work. But I did find a solution posted by Conner above and placed the full answer I used here. I really appreciate your time in trying to help me solve this though!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much @Conner for the link to [jQuery resize function doesn't work on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597152/jquery-window-resize-doesnt-work-on-load)

Using that code, I was able to whip up this script for smooth scrolling to any article element when clicked but only if the width of the window is greater than 900! Perfect.

```
onResize = function() {
    if($(window).width() > 900){
        $('article').bind('click',function(event){
            var $myPos = $(this);

            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollLeft: $($myPos).offset().left -0
            }, 500, 'easeInOutExpo');
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    }
    else{
        $('article').unbind('click');
    }
}
```