# How can I make a jQuery functions execute on load and on window resize?

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, window-resize

How can I make this function run on load and on window resize?
thanks.

```
jQuery(function( $ ) {
var headerHeight = $("#header").outerHeight();
var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
var elementNewHeight = viewportHeight - headerHeight;
$(".fullHeightThis").outerHeight(elementNewHeight);
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery function triggered on window resize but not on page load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993604/jquery-function-triggered-on-window-resize-but-not-on-page-load)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(function( $ ) {
    function someStuff(){
      var headerHeight = $("#header").outerHeight();
      var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
      var elementNewHeight = viewportHeight - headerHeight;
      $(".fullHeightThis").outerHeight(elementNewHeight);
    }
    someStuff(); //call immediately

    $(window).on('resize', someStuff);

});
```