# Is it normal for $window.resize() to be called on page refresh?

Tags: jquery, resize

I have the following code:

```
  front_page_magic();

  $(window).resize(function() {
    front_page_magic();
  });
```

All the magic happens within `front_page_magic()`, although whenever I load the page the resize function also gets called which creates some whacky and slow behaviour as the function is been called twice in quick succession.

Is this something which is related to certain browsers too?

I though $(window).resize() was only relative to the resizing of the browser window, and had nothing to do with page load/refresh?

Comment: For which browsers you are facing this issue.

Comment: Where do you place this code on the page?

Comment: 1. Create a jsfiddle with your issue. 2. You are calling twice times the `front_page_magic()` when script is loading (not loaded) and then when browser resize is triggered. 3. in this case you can use `$(window).resize(front_page_magic);`

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question. **Nope.** It's not supposed to trigger unless you have a resize event which you either trigger resizing your browswer or triggering it manually.

The one thing you definitely want to look for are things like calling the file more than once, initializing the method more than once, binding that method somewhere else, or triggering the resize event manually.

This answer may be related.

[jQuery resize function doesn't work on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597152/jquery-window-resize-doesnt-work-on-load)

Answer (score 0):

the code executes everytime the page load because you have`front_page_magic();`in there